# Best practice to deal with HATEOAS api callouts

Tags: batch, callout, asynchronous, queueable-apex, etl

I'm creating an connector between Salesforce and a ticketing system that exposes a REST API based on HATEOAS. I need to synchronize tickets everyday and insert/update them as Cases. Salesforce is readonly

The API call returns a JSON containing a list of tickets. For each tickets, we have basic infos and some relations that contains an url pointing to another object record.

Here is an example of api response :

```
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "15d370f0d0f-c0e16",
            "type": "wo",
            "links": {
                "self": "https://apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16",
                "workflow-transitions": "https://
apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16/workflow-transitions"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "expTime": null,
                "remoteChangedDate": null,
                "expectedCost": 0.0,
                "WOBegin": "2017-07-18T08:00:00.000+02:00",
                "actToolCost": 0.0,
                "realisedTimeRate": 0.0,
                "actMiscCost": 0.0,
                "statusChangedDate": "2017-07-18T13:57:49.937+02:00",
                "expMiscCost": 0.0,
                "project": null,
                "providerWorkId": null,
                "late": false,
                "actServiceCost": 0.0,
                "actStockCost": 0.0,
                "fixedDt": false,
                "xtraBool02": null,
                "xtraBool01": null,
                "xtraBool04": null,
                "computeInternalActLabourDuration": 0.0,
                "xtraBool03": null,
                "xtraBool05": null,
                "longitude": null,
                "alsTotalWorkTime": null,
                "modifyDate": "2017-07-18T13:57:49.000+02:00",
                "xtraDate01": null,
                "xtraDate02": null,
                "xtraDate03": null,
            },
            "relationships": {
                "customer": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https://apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16/relationships/customer",
                        "related": "https://apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16/customer"
                    }
                },
                "site": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "https://apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16/relationships/site",
                        "related": "https://apiurl/api/entities/v1/wo/15d370f0d0f-c0e16/site"
                    }
                },
            }
        },
]
```

I need infos about these relations to fill some case fields, like Customer.name for example, which requires another callout.

Considering that I'll retrieve something like 100 tickets and that I'll have to make 5 callouts per ticket, what is the best practice to avoid governor limits ?

I considered trying queuable classes but I heard that when exceeding depth 4 of chain it'll start to slow down.

Thanks in advance for your advices

Comment: For those who haven't heard of HATEOAS before, that's _Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State_. I.e. "the response to one API call includes links to other possible endpoints you can call, and they contain stateful data like account/user ids and ids for related data"

Comment: see [this answer on queueable chain depth and performance](https://codefriar.com/universal-invocable) (as of V57)

Comment: Have you looked at external objects? Might be able to build an apex adapter (I forget the name for them) to expose the data in the Salesforce UI, of course that won't help if you need actual case records.

Comment: Yes indeed @MattLacey I need to store everything into a custom case record type.

I ended up creating a queuable chain that dynamically calculate the remaining callout count and start a new queuable with the rest of the data to process. Works pretty well but is a bit slow, I believe I have to wait for 2 to 3 minutes if there are 200 tickets, thus 1000 callouts.

Considering that the data volumetry is something like 10 tickets / hour or less, it could be a viable solution